# PDF to JPEG conversion algorithm

Tags: pdf, jpeg

I was wondering how the snipping tool works while cropping any vector image, for example an image on pdf file, to jpeg file. Does it use rasterization? Is there any way to convert an image on a PDF file to JPEG image without rasterization?

Answer (score 3):

JPEG is a raster image format, so you cannot convert a vector format to JPEG without rasterization.

Comment: Also, when the snipping tool crops a part of a pdf file and saves it as a jpeg, it uses the same algorithm as converting a vector image to a raster image. Am I correct?